# How can I center a text and keep being left align?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is a simplified of my code:

```css
.wrapper{
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
.icon{
  text-align: center;
}

.icon i{
  font-size: 100px;
  color: gray;
}
.text{
  text-align: center;
}
.text span{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="icon">
    <i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <span><i class="fa fa-check-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> Something </span>
    <span><i class="fa fa-check-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> Something Else </span>
    <span><i class="fa fa-check-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> Some </span>
  </div>

</div>
```

All I want to do is putting all check icons exactly under each other vertically. How can I do that?

Comment: You can give a container a width and `margin:0 auto;` it, with no `text-align:center;`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `text-align:left;` instead, and adjust the width or margin of `.text` to center it

```css
.wrapper{
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
.icon{
  text-align: center;
}

.icon i{
  font-size: 100px;
  color: gray;
}
.text{
  text-align: left;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.text span{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="icon">
    <i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <span><i class="fa fa-check-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> Something </span>
    <span><i class="fa fa-check-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> Something Else </span>
    <span><i class="fa fa-check-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> Some </span>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `text-align:left;` to `.text span` class.

```css
.wrapper{
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding:10px;
}
.icon{
  text-align: center;
}

.icon i{
  font-size: 100px;
  color: gray;
}
.text{
  text-align: center;
}
.text span{
  display: block;
  text-align:left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="icon">
    <i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <span><i class="fa fa-check-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> Something </span>
    <span><i class="fa fa-check-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> Something Else </span>
    <span><i class="fa fa-check-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> Some </span>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use ul/li for your list, I think it's more appropriate in your case
You can check this version:

```css
.wrapper{
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
.icon{
  text-align: center;
}

.icon i{
  font-size: 100px;
  color: gray;
}
.text{
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.text li i{
  float: left;
}
.text span{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="icon">
    <i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
  <ul class="text">
    <li><i class="fa fa-check-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span>Something </span></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-check-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span>Something Else </span></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-check-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span>Some </span></li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With a simple `margin:auto` and `text-align:left`  in the `div.text` you can achieve this:

```css
.wrapper{
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
.icon{
  text-align: center;
}

.icon i{
  font-size: 100px;
  color: gray;
}
.text{
  text-align: left;
  margin: auto;
  width: 70%;
}
.text span{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="icon">
    <i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <span><i class="fa fa-check-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> Something </span>
    <span><i class="fa fa-check-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> Something Else </span>
    <span><i class="fa fa-check-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> Some </span>
  </div>

</div>
```